# is the allowed in islam to look at first moon of RABI UL AWAL and put our hands up for dua?

Tags: halal-haram, dua, bidah, islamic-events

we have listen to many people to that first look at the moon of RABI UL AWAL AND wish what ever you want will probably come true but some people said that it is haram because moon is the creation of ALLAH and we should not dua in front of moon we should directly ask it from ALLAH SO WHAT is correct.